# Jenkins plugin 'role-based strategy' doesn't load up

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed Jenkins plugin 'role based strategy' on Jenkins and tried enabling under *Manage Jenkins* --> *Configure Global Security* and scrolled down to click on save button and only found missing save button and could not enable role based strategy plugin option. Any pointers to fix this error would be great,thanks

Jenkins version: 2.368
role-based strategy plugin version: 569.v7476f8e4fe29

[image: Jenkins error msg on the configure global security page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use LTS jenkins version and java 11.

Comment: The Java I have is openjdk 11.0.16 any specific LTS Jenkins version we need to use to fix the error above ?

Comment: As you are using jenkins 2.368 weekly version it will be safely to upgrade to 2.371.1 LTS jenkins version. I can't promise you jenkins will be alive but this is a good practise to run jenkins LTS. ALso in case upgrading jenkins wouldn't help try to use different versions of role based strategy plugin.

Comment: latest jenkins LTS version is 2.375.1